# Find unique counts over rolling two weeks

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have a list of students and what they drink on certain days

```
╔════════════╤═════════╤═══════╤═══════╤═══════════════╗
║ Day        │ Student │ Class │ Group │ Drinks        ║
╠════════════╪═════════╪═══════╪═══════╪═══════════════╣
║ 2019-04-08 │ A       │ 3A1   │ 1     │ Coke          ║
╟────────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼───────────────╢
║ 2019-04-09 │ A       │ 3A1   │ 1     │ Lemon Juice   ║
╟────────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼───────────────╢
║ 2019-04-16 │ A       │ 3A1   │ 1     │ Green Tea     ║
╟────────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼───────────────╢
║ 2019-04-20 │ A       │ 3A1   │ 1     │ Green Tea     ║
╟────────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼───────────────╢
║ 2019-04-01 │ B       │ 3B1   │ 3     │ Pepsi         ║
╟────────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼───────────────╢
║ 2019-04-02 │ B       │ 3B1   │ 3     │ Apple Juice   ║
╟────────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼───────────────╢
║ 2019-04-03 │ B       │ 3B1   │ 3     │ Mineral Water ║
╚════════════╧═════════╧═══════╧═══════╧═══════════════╝
```

I want to find how many unique drinks each student have on a rolling 14 days (Every Monday to following Sunday). The final output should be something like this

```
╔═════════════╤═════════╤═══════╤═══════╤════════════════════╗
║ Week Ending │ Student │ Class │ Group │ Unique Drink Count ║
╠═════════════╪═════════╪═══════╪═══════╪════════════════════╣
║ 2019-04-14  │ A       │ 3A1   │ 1     │ 2                  ║
╟─────────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼────────────────────╢
║ 2019-04-21  │ A       │ 3A1   │ 1     │ 3                  ║
╟─────────────┼─────────┼───────┼───────┼────────────────────╢
║ 2019-04-14  │ B       │ 3B1   │ 3     │ 3                  ║
╚═════════════╧═════════╧═══════╧═══════╧════════════════════╝
```

Explanation:

- Week starting 2019-04-01 to 2019-04-14: Student A drank Coke and Lemon Juice
- Week starting 2019-04-08 to 2019-04-21: Student A drank Coke, Lemon Juice and Green Tea
- Week starting 2019-04-01 to 2019-04-14: Student B drank Pepsi, Apple Juice and Mineral Water

I am using Oracle database 11g so I am afraid there is no lateral join nor outer apply.

Comment: What you are describing is simply an aggregation by 2-week periods.  I don't see any "rolling" component to this.

Comment: You are right. Updated example to illustrate rolling component better. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `union all`

```
select
  '2019-04-14' as week_day,
    student,
    class,
    groups,
    count(distinct drinks) as total_unique_drinks
from students
where day >= '2019-04-01'
and day <= '2019-04-14'
group by
    student,
    class,
    groups

union all

select
  '2019-04-28',
    student,
    class,
    groups,
    count(distinct drinks)
from students
where day >= '2019-04-15'
and day <= '2019-04-28'
group by
    student,
    class,
    groups
```

Output:

```
| week_day   | student | class | groups | total_unique_drinks |
| ---------- | ------- | ----- | ------ | ------------------- |
| 2019-04-14 | A       | 3A1   | 1      | 2                   |
| 2019-04-14 | B       | 3B1   | 3      | 3                   |
| 2019-04-28 | A       | 3A1   | 1      | 1                   |
```

Comment: Thanks! However there is a year's worth of data. How do I make this more dynamic?

Answer (score 0):

*You can group by 14 days periods.*
this script works only data which has date smaller than 29.xx.xxxx.

```
  select student,
         class,
         group,
           day
         + (case
               when TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (day, 'dd')) > 14
               then
                  28 - TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (day, 'dd'))
               else
                  14 - TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (day, 'dd'))
            end),
         COUNT (distinct (drinks))
    from students
group by student,
         dt,
         class,
         group,
         + (case
               when TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (dt, 'dd')) > 14
               then
                  28 - TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (dt, 'dd'))
               else
                  14 - TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (dt, 'dd'))
            end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the week number for the year using the `IW` format.  Then, divide by 2:

```
select min(day), student, class, group, count(distinct drink)
from (select s.*,
             to_number(to_char(day, 'IW')) - 1 as week_number
      from students s
     ) s
group floor(week_number / 2), student, class, group;
```

It is not clear if you want to start on even or odd weeks, so the `- 1` may not be necessary.

Note that `group` is a really bad name for a column because it is a SQL keyword.

Answer (score 0):

That you have/want a year's worth of data significantly changes the question. In the future please make sure that type information is included even if the sample data does not.  
However, what you want by the description is not overly difficult (I added both start and end of the 14 day periods):

```
with parm(proc_year) as
       (select &proc_year from dual)
  , cal(proc_year,start_period, end_period) as 
       (select proc_year
             , next_day(to_date(to_char(proc_year)||'0104','yyyymmdd')-7,'mon')
             , next_day(to_date(to_char(proc_year)||'0104','yyyymmdd')-7,'mon')+13 from parm 
        union all 
        select proc_year,start_period+14, end_period+14
           from cal
         where extract(year from end_period) <= proc_year
       )
select to_char(c.start_period, 'yyyy-mm-dd')  "14 Day Start"
     , to_char(c.end_period, 'yyyy-mm-dd')    "14 Day Ending" 
     , sd.student                             "Student" 
     , sd.class                               "Class"
     ,sd.group_cd                             "Group"
     , count(distinct drinks)                 "Unique Drink Count"  
  from cal                 c
  left join student_drinks sd
         on trunc(sd.day) between c.start_period and c.end_period
  group by c.end_period
         , sd.student
         , sd.class
         , sd.group_cd  
         , c.start_period
  order by sd.student
         , c.end_period ;
```

**How it works**  
The main driver is the recursive CTE (cal) which builds a 14day calendar for the requested year. The heart of this is the base query of the recursive CTE (introduced in 11gR2). This query determines the first week according to ISO8601* definition, and the last day of a 14 day period beginning then. The recursive part then calculates remaining 14 day periods for that year. The main query is then just a basic count query.  
  
**The Result** (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b97f227af0355780bad748f692f54536)):  
Given your data it gives the "something like" your output. But it cannot be produced exactly:

- Your sample data contains 7 rows, but your output only accounts for
  6 rows. (2+1+3).
- The dates of your output do not correspond to the end of a 14 day period from the 1st week of the year. They represent the end of 14day period from 1st week of April. However that date is the beginning of the 2nd week of a 14day period.
- "Every Monday to following Sunday" is only a 7day period. You need "every other Monday to the 2nd Sunday following".

```
*ISO8601 can produce unexpected results at the transaction from 1 year to another.
  - Every week begins on Monday and is always 7 days long;
  - The 1st week of the year begins Monday on or preceding 4-Jan.

As a result of the above the 1st week of a year may begin in the prior
year and include the last days of Dec. Also the 1st days in Jan may be 
included in the last week (52 or 53) of the prior year.
```